# Spring Data JPA returning wrong results

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, http-request-parameters

I am testing Spring-Data-JPA with Spring-Boot, using hibernate-core 5.4.2.Final version.

For example, I have a `Users` table containing **address** and other columns.

My repository interface for this table is as below.

```java
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

    List<Users> findByAddressContaining(String keyword)
}
```

To my knowledge, if I name the method like I did, the query below will be executed.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE address LIKE '%keyword%';
```

The problem is, this **partly** works.

For example, there are two datas in `users` table, each datas having address of "abc" and "cde".

If i test the `findByAddressContaing("abc")`, the result size of `List<>` is 2.
Right after if I run `findByAddressContaining("de")`, the result should be 1, but it is 2.
If i run the same method `findByAddressContaining("de")` again, then the result becomes 1.

I can't find the way to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be helpful. :)

## THE PROBLEM WAS NOT WITH THE Spring-Data-JPA, it was with Request Parameter.

This is my controller method.

```java
@GetMapping("/v2/warehouses")
public void getAllWarehouses(@RequestParam(name = "address") String address,
                             @RequestParam(name = "limit") Integer limit,
                             @RequestParam(name = "offset") Integer offset,
                             HttpServletResponse response) {
        
    System.err.println("Request Param Address : " + address");
```

If I send request to the correct path using Postman, sometimes address comes as blank.("")

Does this happen normally??

Comment: Please show a complete code example, including inserting the data and querying the method and an initial query demonstrating that the database is empty to start with.

Comment: Try to print the translated SQL query so you can check. Add these to your properties file: `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`

Comment: @JensSchauder Complete code is quite complex, so I made a sample code so I can put it simply.

Answer (score 0):

So the basic problem was not with the `@RequestParam` annotation, it was with the `application.properties` file.

After I added `server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8` to the properties file, the bug didn't happen anymore.

Thanks!